# Equivalent to Application.ScreenUpdating Property in office-js Excel add-in

Tags: office-js

I am inserting a lot of data into a sheet and the screen flickers when doing so. In VBA and com add-ins there's a property I can set to delay the updates until they're finished.

Is there an equivalent to Application.ScreenUpdating Property in office-js add-ins for excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent for it in Office.js -- not yet, at any rate.  There are a number of technical issues that prevent this (FWIW, if you're curious, try toggling ScreenUpdating in VBA while you have a taskpane open; you'll see what I mean).

There are some longer-term ideas that may help with this issue, but to be very transparent, I would expect that it's months and months away.  That said, I do encourage you to file a suggestion on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ (or search if one already exists) and describe your scenario and/or link to a video of the issue you're currently seeing, so we can get it up on folks' radar.

Comment: I have to say, that I do appreciate the official answers of "No" so people don't bang there head on the wall, and that I see lots of progress!! 2 Q's today that went from No/WIP to complete! https://stackoverflow.com/a/71535044/5079799

Answer (score 1):

See --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/performance#suspend-screen-updating

Note: The example is horrible...

`Application.suspendScreenUpdatingUntilNextSync()` gives error `'Application' is undefined`

Use:

```
context.workbook.application.suspendScreenUpdatingUntilNextSync()
```

I noticed a dramatic improvement.

The be honest, what I ended up doing is not switching to the new worksheet until the formatting was complete. I think this is best "approach" where possible. You can even switch to a blank/temp worksheet and delete after if needed.