# How to group rows or columns in Excel using Office JS API

Tags: excel, office-js

I am converting a VSTO Excel add-in to a Web Excel add-in (using JavaScript API for Office). In my VSTO C# code I have the following line:

```
worksheet.Rows[rowStart + ":" + rowEnd].Group()
```

and a similar line for columns:

```
worksheet.Columns[colStart + ":" + colEnd].Group();
```

What is the equivalent API call for Office-JS? Could not find a relevant entry in the [API Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=office-js#methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that that kind of grouping is not yet supported in office.js. Please vote up the suggestion in the Office Developer Suggestion box: [Grouping and ungrouping rows and columns](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15683472-grouping-ungrouping-rows-and-columns).

Comment: Thanks Rick. When I started the conversion from VSTO to office.js, I went in with the expectation of parity between the capabilities of the two frameworks, but this example proves me wrong. Can you think of a document that catalogs the gaps in office.js like this one?

Comment: I'm sorry. There's no list like that. The best you can do is look through the [Excel Requirement Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets) and the Excel JavaScript API reference: [Released Excel APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel_release?view=office-js).

Comment: Rick, you guys should update your SO Posts! Feel like I'm on the "bleeding edge" of new tech kinda :P, This is my 2nd post today w/ an "official" answer of "no thats not possible" that I get to answer/ with "Here is how" (obviously it wasn't at the time). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71533702/5079799

Answer (score 1):

See --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-ranges-group

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-group-member(1)

Here is how I did it. First thing I noticed was that I wanted certain groups to be collapsed by default. I accomplished this w/ `hidden = true` which combined w/ grouping, its more of a `hide by default`.

```
const Rng_Group_Obj = {
    "group": {
        "groupOptionString": {
            "ByRows": "ByRows",
            "ByColumns": "ByColumns",
        },
    },
    "columnHidden": true,
    "rowHidden": true,
}
```

---

```
function Do_Group_Rng(rng, ByColumns, ByRows, Opt_Hidden_By_Default) {
    if (ByColumns == true) {
        rng.group(Rng_Group_Obj.group.groupOptionString.ByColumns)
        if (Opt_Hidden_By_Default == true) { rng.columnHidden = Rng_Group_Obj.columnHidden }
    }
    if (ByRows == true) {
        rng.group(Rng_Group_Obj.group.groupOptionString.ByRows)
        if (Opt_Hidden_By_Default == true) { rng.rowHidden = Rng_Group_Obj.rowHidden }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet()

var rng = ws.getRange("G:K")
Do_Group_Rng(rng,true,false,true)

var rng = ws.getRange("4:7")
Do_Group_Rng(rng, false, true, true)
```

Comment: This was the first time in the docs I saw you can get a range via `getRange` w/ numbers!! Getting a range via letters is so `its my first time writing a macro in VBA`. I've been using `getRangeByIndexes` but boy did that take some re-arranging my brain from VBA to get used to. Using #'s in `getRange`  might just be perfect for me, though it will be reminiscent of my VBA days. Picture `getRange(Int_var + ":" + IntTwo_var)` ... Untested, wondering if I'll need Triple `"""` or some `Chr(#)` foo lol. Good old times in VBA.

Comment: I guess thats only rows tho, no cols. I'm getting used to `getRangeByIndexes` but it wasn't easy.

Comment: So....`getRange` isn't zero indexed like `getRangeByIndexes` so thats out.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's JavaScript API does now support grouping and ungrouping rows and columns, collapsing them (hiding their details), and expanding them (showing their details).

You can group rows (or columns) via the [`group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-group-member(1)) method, ungroup them via [`ungroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-ungroup-member(1)), hide the details of the group (like using the `[-]` button to the left of the grouped rows) via [`hideGroupDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-hidegroupdetails-member(1)), and show the details of the group (like clicking the `[+]` button to the left of the grouped rows) via [`showGroupDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-showgroupdetails-member(1)).

Assuming your `rowStart` and `rowEnd` are cell/range reference strings, then:

```js
worksheet.getRange(`${rowStart}:${rowEnd}`).group(Excel.GroupOption.byRows);
```